Fractional Box counting for fractal dimension estimation
  #Z = Z < 0.9
        S = np.add.reduceat(
            np.add.reduceat(Z, np.arange(0, Z.shape[0], k), axis=0),
                               np.arange(0, Z.shape[1], k), axis=1)
        return len(np.where((S > 0) & (S < k*k))[0])

def fractional_boxcount(Z, k):
    M, N = Z.shape #Get height and width

    m = M // k   #integer division to yield number of boxes without falling off the grid
    n = N // k

    #Z = (Z < 0.9) #use threshold value to transform image into a binary array

    # Count full blocks
    full_blocks_count = integer_box_count(Z, k)

    # Initialize fractional count
    fractional_count = 0

    # Calculate fractional contribution of blocks extending beyond boundaries
    if M % k > 0:
        for j in range(n):
            block = Z[m*k:, j*k:(j+1)*k]
            p_ij = np.sum(block)
            p_bar_delta = np.sum(Z[:m*k, :]) / (n + 1) #WRONG here
            fractional_count += min(p_ij / p_bar_delta, 1) * (N - n*k) / k

    if N % k > 0:
        for i in range(m):
            block = Z[i*k:(i+1)*k, n*k:]
            p_ij = np.sum(block)
            p_bar_delta = np.sum(Z[:, :n*k]) / (m + 1)
            fractional_count += min(p_ij / p_bar_delta, 1) * (M - m*k) / k

    if M % k > 0 and N % k > 0:
        block = Z[m*k:, n*k:]
        p_ij = np.sum(block)
        p_bar_delta = np.sum(Z[:m*k, :n*k]) / (m + 1) / (n + 1)
        fractional_count += min(p_ij / p_bar_delta, 1) * (M - m*k) * (N - n*k) / (k*k)

    if k==1: 
      fractional_count = np.sum(Z)

    return full_blocks_count + fractional_count

I am trying to implement the fractional box counting algorithm as outlined in this paper:
https://doi.org/10.1016/j.patrec.2017.08.022
However, I am just not able to compute the correct FD for a test image: a vonKoch curve with resolution 409x1502 pixels.
Furthermore, my normal FD method which uses only integer box counting with OUT the optimal box sizes as outline in the paper, gets a VERY good estimate of the FD of the vonKoch curve.
I've been bashing my head against this for a week and have no idea what to do.
Any input at all would be appreciated.
For this image, the box sizes and counts generated via normal box counting is:
counts = [256,128,64,32,16,8,4]
standardBC = [9, 32, 76, 166, 411, 913, 2049]
and according to this paper, this is what I get:
optimal_Counts = [1,2,3,4,6,8,11,16,23,32,45,64,128]
fBC = [605232, 3834.0, 2917.942090751407, 2049.517919144537, 1272.2265918840258, 913.3849312089329, 637.4095814218092, 413.25673523937985, 261.06083715854834, 169.56125645733385, 128.13886470863284, 76.80333954303595, 32.611286713654586]
I know my optimal_counts are right since I have verified this with pen and paper calculations.
I am under the impression that my fBC values are correct because I get values that are so close with the integer box count values. However this assumption could be wrong
And so when I try to work out the gradient of the line of best fit via LLS regression via np.polyfit,
I get 1.27 ish for the standard box counting method
and only 1.16 for my implementation of the methods outlined on this paper.
I really am not sure what I am doing wrong, I have been trying for a week now to get a correct answer. I'm just not sure where I'm faltering.
Furthermore, the plots of the counts and the sizes seem to align really well:

Any help would be appreciated
